# Docker nginx cannot reverse proxy within default network

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm having problems with nginx reverse proxying as a docker container. My question is about how to correctly proxy pass nginx in a default docker network?

Here's my docker-compose.yml (unnecessary details omitted for brevity)

```
    version: '3'

    networks:
      nginx_default:
          external: true

    services:
      db:
        image: postgres:10.2
        ports:
          - "5432:5432"
        environment: ...

      postgrest:
        image: postgrest/postgrest
        ports:
          - "3000:3000"
        environment: ...

      nginx:
        restart: always
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
          - "8080:80"
        volumes:
          - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ruler
        command: [nginx-debug, '-g', 'daemon off;']

      webapp:
        build:
          context: "./"
          dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
        volumes: ...
        ports:
          - "3001:3001"
        environment: ...
```

Here's my nginx.conf

```
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
      default upgrade;
      ''      close;
    }

    server {
      listen 80;
      server_name _;

      gzip on;
      gzip_proxied any;
      gzip_types text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript;
      gzip_vary on;
      gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

      access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
      error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

      location / {
        try_files $uri @node;
      }

      location /api/ {
        try_files $uri @postgrest;
      }

      location @node {
        proxy_pass http://webapp:3001;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;

        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_cache_bypass $http_cache_control;
        add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
      }

      location @postgrest {
        proxy_pass http://postgrest:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;

        default_type application/json;

        proxy_set_header  Connection "";
        proxy_hide_header Content-Location;
        add_header Content-Location  /api/$upstream_http_content_location;
      }
    }
```

And my Dockerfile.dev

```
    FROM node:8.9

    WORKDIR /client

    CMD npm run dev -- -p 3001
```

When I do `$ docker-compose up -d` everything starts without an error. After that I can successfully do `$ curl http://127.0.0.1:3001/` (webapp) and `$ curl http://127.0.0.1:3000` (postgrest).

But when I try `$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/` (nginx should handle here the proxying) I get default nginx welcome page. Also `$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/` is not hitting the API :/

What may be the cause? Using `$ docker inspect` I see that every container is in the same default network.

Edit: Using `$ docker-compose logs` seems like the default network is not used at all O_o

```
    docker-compose logs
    WARNING: Some networks were defined but are not used by any service: nginx_default
    Attaching to ruler_webapp_1, ruler_nginx_1
    webapp_1  | 
    webapp_1  | > ruler@ dev /client
    webapp_1  | > next "-p" "3001"
    webapp_1  | 
    webapp_1  | > Using external babel configuration
    webapp_1  | > Location: "/client/.babelrc"
    webapp_1  |  DONE  Compiled successfully in 1741ms09:04:49
    webapp_1  |
```

Comment: Can you post the nginx logs also?

Comment: @TarunLalwani there's nothing in `/var/log/nginx/access.log` and `/var/log/nginx/error.log` :/

Comment: It will be in `docker-compose logs`

Comment: @TarunLalwani I've updated the SO question. There's a warning that nginx_default is not used. Btw I thought that all composed containers are reachable in their default network https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/ without explicitly telling them that there's a default network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you mapped your local nginx configuration file to the wrong file on the container side. The default configuration file for the `nginx` image is located at `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` so the volume of the `nginx` container should be:

```
./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
```

You can check your configuration file is used correctly by executing:

```
docker-compose exec nginx nginx -T
```

Side notes:

1. Never use the `latest` tag, because in some time you may face broken compatibility issues. Use fixed version tag `1`, `1.13` etc. instead
2. You don't need to publish ports everywhere, eg. `3000:3000`, `3001:3001`. Those ports will be accessible internally by containers

Comment: is spot on, because as of now you are loading just one config default.conf and not `ruler` as the extension for the file needs to be `conf`. So even for it to get loaded you should have used `ruler.conf` and also deleted the `default.conf` or overwritten it using volumes

Comment: @Mike yes, I've tried that already. With this nginx conf mapping when I try `$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/api` I see in the logs `nginx_1   | 2018/02/16 09:22:30 [error] 7#7: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/api" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /api HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080"`

Comment: Have you tried `curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/` instead? Your `location` definition requires trailing `/`

Comment: @Mike yes, still getting nginx 404 page. Thanks for the eagle eye though! :))) Also `curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/` should proxy me to the webapp but that's not happening as well

Comment: @Mike Yup, still no success

Comment: Can you confirm your configuration is used correctly? With `docker-compose exec nginx nginx -T` This will return currently used nginx configuration to stdout.

Comment: Like I said your volume mapping is incorrect. There's no magic here. Always first thing to do when running a Docker project is to check volumes are mounted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your config is a partial config and not a complete nginx config. So it needs to go inside `conf.d` inside the container and not on `nginx.conf` or `sites-enabled`. So change

```
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ruler
```

to

```
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

And now it should start working

Comment: Nope, he has full nginx config which should go to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

Comment: @Mike, if you check the contents of the `nginx.conf` he posted, it doesn't have `http` block in. And the `nginx.conf` inside the docker container has the http block which has `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;`. So he needs to get this config inside the `conf.d` and not overwrite the `nginx.conf`.